# Selecting latest record from multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of tables that look like this:

```
resource
---------
id
name

meta1
---------
id
resource_id
value
created_on

meta2
---------
id
resource_id
value
created_on

meta3
---------
id
resource_id
value
created_on
```

How can I get a result set containing the latest `value` from each of the `meta` tables for a given resource id using mysql?

I tried joining all the tables together on `resource_id` and selecting the `max(created_on)` and `value` columns from each `meta` tables. That would indeed give me the most recent `created_on` however the `value` is incorrect.

Comment: `MAX` ? or `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish your result with a series of cross joins:

```
SELECT id, t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
FROM resource r
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT value
    FROM meta1 m1
    WHERE m1.resource_id = 10
    ORDER BY created_on DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT value
    FROM meta2 m2
    WHERE m2.resource_id = 10
    ORDER BY created_on DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t2
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT value
    FROM meta3 m3
    WHERE m3.resource_id = 10
    ORDER BY created_on DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t3
WHERE r.id = 10
```

I used the resource id `10` in the above query but you can replace it with whatever you want.